# Why is my Drupal site database using up so much server space?

Tags: drupal-7

I have a small Drupal 7 blog site with around 30 blog posts. I have the Backup & Migrate module enabled and it is backing up my entire site weekly, and the size of the backup file is ~40MB. However, to my great surprise, I'm very close to exceeding the 5GB disk space quota of my shared hosting account.

I deleted most of the stored backups, and the amount of disk space being used is still hovering at around 4GB, which is ridiculously large considering the scale of my site.

Any idea what could be using up so much space? Also appreciated would be tips on how I can find what files/directories are taking the most space, since the cPanel File Manager is really not very handy in doing that.

Edit: I found a tool to analyze disk space usage in the cPanel, and it turns out that my site's mySQL database is taking up over 4GB of space. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please check these following points

1. If there is any bots filling data in your mysql like dummy comments, dummy users or any forms which store data in your site.
2. Check the cache tables and check if their expire in time.
3. Check what table is occupying most of the space by sorting the tables based on memory column by using phpmyadmin of your cpannel.

Note: Use different types of capchas, recapchas, spam checkers in your website so as to check the bots filling the data.

If you find any of the points 1, 2, 3 in your site please update your question / add new question so that it can be fixed.

Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks! I sorted the tables in my database by size, and sure enough something weird was going on. The **cache_form** table has a size of 4.3GB, so apparently my site is being attacked by some sort of spam bot? Can I just drop the **cache_form** table from phpMyAdmin, or will it break something?

Comment: Stop, please don't drop it. Just truncate / empty it, that will solve your problem